# file io with /dev/random takes too long

Tags: c++

I want to write a program to generate really random number using `/dev/random` on linux, but later I find the running time of it is quite unacceptable occasionally. C version of it run fast consistently.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    ifstream random("/dev/random", ios_base::in);
    int t;
    random.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(t));
    cout << t << endl;
    random.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The time statistic of running time

```
$: time ./random 
-1040810404

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

$: time ./random 
-1298913761

real    0m4.119s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: "really random number" no such thing in the entire Computer-Science-world, explain yourself in better terms

Comment: `/dev/random` depends on interupts and other hardware-type events for data. This means that it's pretty random, but also that you must sometimes wait (as you've seen, sometimes it's a long time you must wait even for a few bytes). Your C version is likely using `/dev/urandom` rather than `/dev/random`.

Comment: @Corbin this post is tagged as "C++" ... I still don't get the point ...

Comment: @user2485710 Yeah, he mentioned that "C version of it run fast consistently", so it sounds like he's trying to blame C++. I'm a bit confused as well.

Comment: Try calling `random.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(NULL, 0);` after opening the file but before reading the data to disable buffering on the file stream.

Comment: If you are lucky, your hardware will include a "true" RNG. Try searches for `hw_random` and `rng_utils`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have likely drained the entropy pool.  Creating (ok harvesting) entropy is based on device drivers which sample qualities of the physical world which are mostly unpredictable.  But if those devices are not very active or if the entropy-producing algorithm stalls, your reads from `/dev/random` will too.

Can you use `/dev/urandom`?  If not, you should look into ways that you can produce more entropy in a more deterministic fashion.

Here are some suggestions from an [article regarding a similar problem](http://www.usn-it.de/index.php/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/):

- Involve an audio entropy daemon like AED to gather noise from your datacenter with an open microphone, maybe combine it with a webcam noise collector like VED. Other sources are talking about “Cryptographic Randomness from Air Turbulence in Disk devices“. :)
- Use the Entropy Gathering Daemon to collect weaker entropy from randomness of userspace programs.

Comment: Furthermore, a `std::ifstream` is buffered by default, so it's quite likely that each run of the program is trying to read several KB of data into the file buffer, which will drain the entropy pool orders of magnitude faster than reading 4 bytes per run of the program.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield If the C input isn't buffered as exorbitantly (not sure OTOH), that could explain the cross-language difference.

Comment: IMO @AdamRosenfield's answer is the likely "correct" answer.  `setbuf(0, 0)` is probably what OP wants.